# How can I manage historical answers for different versions?

Tags: discussion, answers

Answers to question [How do you alias a type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045222/how-do-you-alias-a-type-in-python) trickled in with time, and are bringing in new functionalities by version.

In order to make the answers stand out with the version the answer applies to, I added a prominent version header for each of them. I feel however that it would be better, ultimately, to regroup the answers and have one going through the versions and the features they brought in.

What is the consensus of such answers (all good) that cover the history of the introduction of a feature?

Comment: I think your technique is fine. If you want to add a "summary" answer, that's fine too. I've done that before, back when I wrote answers.

Comment: I don't like questions which trigger this kind of answering so my beef would be higher up the chain. But it exists, the answers are happening, we're creating another list of things. Yay. Given that the situation is already in existence, I think what you did makes the best of it.

Comment: This was a topic of discussion in the [Outdated Answers Project](/q/405302), but nothing material ever came of it in terms of version tagging, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gimby I don't think there's a clear delineation of "questions which trigger this kind of answering". The question has those answers because new ways to solve the problem became possible with new language features. OP couldn't have predicted that at the time of asking.

Comment: just do it? if the problem is that you'd feel bad about getting rep for it, just slap a community wiki on it.